# How to structure a query with a large, complex where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an SQL query that takes these parameters:

```
@SearchFor  nvarchar(200) = null 
,@SearchInLat Decimal(18,15) = null
,@SearchInLng Decimal(18,15) = null
,@SearchActivity int = null
,@SearchOffers bit = null
,@StartRow int
,@EndRow int
```

The variables `@SearchFor`, `@SearchActivity`, `@SearchOffers` can be either null or not null. `@SearchInLat` and `@SearchInLng` must both null, or both have values.

I'm not going to post the whole query as its boring and hard to read, but the WHERE clause is shaped like this:

```
( -- filter by activity --
    (@SearchActivity IS NULL)
    OR (@SearchActivity = Activities.ActivityID)
)
AND ( -- filter by Location --
    (@SearchInLat is NULL AND @SearchInLng is NULL)
    OR ( ... )
)
AND ( -- filter by activity --
    @SearchActivity is NULL
    OR ( ... )
)
AND ( -- filter by has offers --
    @SearchOffers is NULL
    OR ( ... )
)
AND (
    ... -- more stuff
)
```

I have read that this is a bad way to structure a query - that SqlServer has trouble working out an efficient execution plan with lots of clauses like this, so I'm looking for other ways to do it.

I see two ways of doing this:

1. Construct the query as a string in my client application, so that the `WHERE` clause only contains filters for the relevant parameters. The problem with this is it means not accessing the database through stored procedures, as everything else is at the moment.
2. Change the stored procedure so that it examines which arguments are null, and executes child procedures depending on which arguments it is passed. The problem here is that it would mean repeating myself a lot in the definition of the procs, and thus be harder to maintain.

What should I do? Or should I just keep on as I am currently doing? I have `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` set for the procedures, but I've heard that this doesn't work right in Server 2005. Also, I plan to add more parameters to this proc, so I want to make sure whatever solution I have is fairly scaleable.

Comment: **Premature optimization is the root of all evil.**  Have you tried  the current query?  Does it work fast enough?

Comment: You could also build your query in a string, only adding to the WHERE clause when needed and then executing the string.  You may still have the issues with the execution plan this way

Comment: @Jnk It's already super slow but I'm having a lot of trouble fixing that. I don't want it to get even slower as I add more parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to use DynamicSQL (be it in the client, or in an SP using `sp_executesql`), but the reason why is long, so here's a link...

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

A very short version is that one-size does not fit all.  And as the optimiser creates one plan for one query, it's slow.  So the solution is to continue using parameterised queries (for execution plan caching), but to have many queries, for the different types of search that can happen.

Comment: Does execution plan caching work if I use `sp_executesql` from the client application, so long as I use parameters?

Comment: @Oliver - Yes, though I'm not aware of a reason that you'd need to use it directly.  Most frameworks (ADO.NET, etc) will allow you to build up the query dynamically, and parameteris them.  Either method give plan caching.  I'd only use sp_executesql if the query being built is being built in t-sql.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an alternative might be to perform several separate select statements?

e.g.

```
( -- filter by activity --
if @SearchActivity is not null
    insert into tmpTable (<columns>)
    select *
    from myTable
    where (@SearchActivity = Activities.ActivityID)
)

( -- filter by Location --
if @SearchInLat is not null and @SearchInLng is not null
    insert into tmpTable (<columns>)
    select *
    from myTable
    where (latCol = @SearchInLat AND lngCol = @SearchInLng)
```

etc...

then select the temp table to return the final result set.

I'm not sure how this would work with respect to the optimiser and the query plans, but each individual select would be very straightforward and could utilise the indexes that you would have created on each column which should make them very quick.

Depending on your requirements it also may make sense to create a primary key on the temp table to allow you to join to it on each select (to avoid duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the performance first, like others have said.

If possible, you can use IF clauses to simplify the queries based on what parameters are provided.

You could also use functions or views to encapsulate some of the code if you find you are repeating it often.